# Pass an event on the whole view hierarchy

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiview-hierarchy

I have created a "classic" category on ui controller to present in my way an other controller.

```
@interface UIViewController (QZPopup)
- (void)presentPopupViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion;
- (void)dismissPopupViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion;
@end
```

The category adds:

- a blurred view on top of the calling controller view
- an invisible view on top of all the screen. this invisible view must catch touch event to dismiss the popup and after having dismissed the popup, I also want to transmit this event to do anything required.

For my usage, I have a `UIController` embedded in a `UINavigationBarController`. I want to have the part below the navigation bar blurred and the navigation bar visible. A touch on the blurred view just dismiss and a touch on the navigation bar must dismiss AND do anything required by touched items in the navigationbar.

Visual is ok on my side, but I have trouble to pass the event and reach the navigationbar. For the moment I have subclassed `UIView` in `QZPopupDismiss` like below:

```
@implementation QZPopupDismiss {
    touchCallback _touchCompletion;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andTouchCompletion:(touchCallback)completion {
    if (self = [self initWithFrame:frame]) {
        _touchCompletion = completion;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    // first do the touch completion
    _touchCompletion();

    // pass the event to the view hierarchy
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
@end
```

But the fact is that, in `touchsEnded`, `super` does not reach the navigation bar. How can I pass my event to the whole view hierarchy to reach the navigation bar items ?